# How to generate android apk without Android Studio using IONIC

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, ionic4

I have created an app in ionic framework. Now i want to generate APK of my code without using Android Studio. But i am getting this error.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running git rev-parse HEAD (exit code 128)

will you please help me. I haven't use ionic before.

I followed this link : https://medium.com/@dineshuthakota/how-to-generate-android-apk-without-android-studio-using-ionic-b3a2ae0edc86

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the link you used, are not correct.

Since it's cordova, you need to add platform in your app as well. cd into your project folder and run the following command in root/folder in terminal:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Then run :

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Try this link for instructions:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

after adding cordova platform with

```
ionic cordova platform add android (for android users)
ionic cordova platform add ios     (for ios users)
```

you can run,

```
ionic cordova run android -lc (for android users)
ionic cordova run ios -lc (for ios users)
```

For mac a setup guide :
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html

this will create a localhost and link to debug so that you can run your code and make changes side by side without having to redeploy each time.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but anyone who wants to generate an apk just using the command line interface, do the following.

1. cd project_root
2. ionic build
3. ionic cap add android
4. cd project_root/android
5. gradlew assembleDebug

You can access the apk from `project_rrot\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`